# Connection faild while using tomcat and mysql

Tags: java, tomcat

i am trying to resolve the issue when i start the tomcat9.0 server(school project) but it shows me on web :Connection failed.

```
INFO: Server startup in [608] milliseconds
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:449)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:242)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
    at it.polimi.tiw.jdbctest.ConnectionTester.doGet(ConnectionTester.java:23)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

My .java prg is

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ConnectionTester extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbtest?serverTimezone=UTC";
        final String USER = "root";
        final String PASS = "cerith12985    ";
        String result = "Connection worked";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = "Connection failed";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(result);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

I have searched my password if i typed it correct in mysql but it is correct,
so i don't really know what is happening.
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You have extra spaces in your password  final String PASS = "cerith12985    ";

Comment: Tried it to delete the extra space but still connection failed:(,still thank you for your time

Comment: is the trace exactly the same as the one you provided above?

Comment: i thank you so much for your help, after another try i did it :)

Comment: no worries, glad I could help